# Open remote file and write to it

Tags: java, http, file-io

I open a txt file on my server, get the Int and want to increment the int by 1 and write it to the file again.

I get the file with this method:

```
    public int getCount() {
        try {
URL updateURL = new URL("http://myserver.gov/text.txt");
URLConnection conn = updateURL.openConnection();
InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);

int current = 0;
while((current = bis.read()) != -1){
    baf.append((byte)current);
}

/* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
String tmp = new String(baf.toByteArray());
int count = Integer.valueOf(tmp);
return count;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "getAdCount Exception = " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

now I simply increment the count and want to write it to the file. 

 I figured out, that it is possible to write to a file with this method:

```
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("text.txt"));
        out.write(count);
        out.close();
```

But how I open the remote file? I dont find a way. Thanks!

**##### Edit: #####** 
I have written this code:

```
        URL url = new URL("http://myserver.gov/text.txt");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
        out.write(count);
        out.close();
```

But it doesnt write the count to the file.

Comment: my bad, for a second I thought that you had to transfer a file to another server, I'll delete my comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to work with URLConnection you can follow the instructions here: [Reading from and Writing to a URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html).

**Update**: You will also need a running server handling POST requests to update your counter.

Comment: Thanks. I used the reference, and have written this code:    `URL url = new URL("http://myserver.gov/text.txt");
   URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
   con.setDoOutput(true);
   OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
   out.write(count);
   out.close();`

But they didn't write the count to it.

Comment: What server is running? How does it handle post requests?

Comment: When you use URLConnection usually HttpURLConnection (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) is instantiated. Then you communicate with the server via http request like GET and POST. When writing you are performing a POST request, when your server does not know what to do with POST-requests, this will not work! I assume this is the case with "simple webspace" ;) . When you look at the example in the link the answer, you will notice a servlet running on the server.

Comment: Nah. Ok, than I have to write a serverApp, too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to me .When you are open remote file.Firstly you have to open connection than read file content.

```
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

than you can write file content.